# remove "\\t\" from a string

Tags: c#

A client added a tab space after the description of his item and now it gets in json like that `( \"Blank Fillers1.5\\\"\\t\" )`, which makes the item not be able to populate its description, I updated the description to remove the tab space from it but couldn't figure out how to replace it to my desired one.
the one after I changed it in the table is `(\"Blank Fillers1.5\\\"\")` and it works I have tried this code below I have seen in other topic but seems like the @ doesn't want to work at all, I also tried to `RTRIM` it in the stored procedure but seems like it doesn't work on SQL 2012, any suggestions ?

```
fieldValue = fieldValue.Replace(@"\\t\", @"\");
```

tl;dr : i need to replace ( " \t\ " ) with  ( " \ " )

Comment: And where is the code that you have tried to fix the problem? Without it and without a sample of your inputs and the expected result, it is really difficult to help you

Comment: the code is right above your comment

Comment: You used a [verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). If you want to replace tabls use `fieldValue.Replace("\t", @"\");` instead. What does the *actual* string look like anyway? What you posted doesn't contain any tabs, it's the escaped form of `"Blank Fillers1.5\"\t"`.

Comment: that "\t" is added because it has a tab space in the sql table, when i updated the column value this "\t" got removed and the json file worked properly, that's why im trying to remove it by replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
      string a = fieldValue; 
       string x = @"\" + "\"" ;

      fieldValue = a.Replace("\\\\t\\",  x);
```

Comment: Except there's no backslash after the `\` and `t` characters. The input string uses normal escape sequences which means it ends in `\`, `t` and `"` at the end

Comment: Sorry, my bad... i just update the awnser

Comment: i actually receive it like that ( \\\\t\ ) on backend, what do i do in that case ? it is one less \ than your code, i tried to modify it to  fieldValue.Replace("\\\\t\"", x);  
 and  i got one quotation mark missing \"Blank Fillers1.5\\\"\

Comment: i will run in here to check the correct format, give me one sec

Comment: string x = @"\" + "\"" ;   try that, you can use blackslash to add a quote inside the string

Comment: Thanks you saved my day

Comment: No problem, have a nice day, if possible upvote the awnser, im new here :D

Comment: i did but it says that new members cant upvote, but i hope some old members will because you deserve it

Comment: yeah i know you did no problem you are new too :D

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you asking but maybe this will help you:

```
var input = @"\\t\";
input = input.Replace("\\\\t\\", "");
```

input will now be an empty string.